# ruby http request post method

Tags: ruby, http, post, request

I want take token,but i have a problems.

My code:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
url = URI.parse('https://ams.iaau.edu.kg/api/authentication/id/password')
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = (url.scheme == 'https')
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
response = http.request(request)
puts response.message
puts response.code
```

I have output like this:

```
Unsupported Media Type
415
```

API Doc

```
URL /api/authentication/:id/:password Method POST 
URL Params Required: id=[Integer] password=[String] hashed in sha256 
Data 
  Params None 
  Success Response: Code: 200 OK 
    Content: {"authToken":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9...", "expires": "2017-10-11T12:13:47.441"} 
  Error Response: Code: 401 Unauthorized 
    Content: {"Status":"Wrong Password"} Code: 401 Unauthorized 
    Content: {"Status":"User doesn't exist"}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to your expectation? right no you are simply making a post request to the given URL without an parameters. 415 means that the payload format is unsupported but since you have no payload on the POST request this is not that surprising. You will most likely need to specify a Content-Type header e.g `application/json` or `text/xml` as well but I am unsure what this service is expecting

Comment: i add parameters to url, like id and password to auth

Comment: i try to connect to university web site, and who write api to this site, give me this: url = URI("https://ams.iaau.edu.kg/api/authentication/13010106044/sha-256 hash")

Comment: URL /api/authentication/:id/:password
Method POST
URL Params Required:
id=[Integer]
password=[String] hashed in sha256

Data Params None
Success Response: Code: 200 OK

Content: {"authToken":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9...",
"expires": "2017-10-11T12:13:47.441"}

Error Response: Code: 401 Unauthorized

Content: {"Status":"Wrong Password"}
Code: 401 Unauthorized
Content: {"Status":"User doesn't exist"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay now that you have posted some information I am going to assume this is a json API because the responses are json.

Update Try this instead

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
uri = URI.parse('https://ams.iaau.edu.kg/api/authentication/id/password')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = (uri.scheme == 'https')
response = http.send_request('POST',uri.request_uri)
```

I am now getting a 401 Unauthorized as expected since I don't have an id or password

If you would prefer your original code I have found the solution which is setting the content type of the request directly e.g.

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
url = URI.parse('https://ams.iaau.edu.kg/api/authentication/id/password')
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = (url.scheme == 'https')
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
request.content_type = 'application/json' # HERE
response = http.request(request)
```

Comment: Now I have :Bad request,400

Comment: That is very strange I will try a few thinsg and get back to you because just using curl I get a 401 with or without content-type specified

Comment: @MaratTynarbekov Please see updated post using this I am now getting a 401 which is as far as I can get without credentials