# Send Post from Rails API 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Sending a request through a RailsAPI is an old topic. However, I didn't see more updated information.

I have a case where I need through a Ruby on Rails (5.1) (+ Grape) API, to receive a user's registration in the API and after saving, send through the API a post with this data to a second API.

How could I do this in the best way?

Because has this GEM: `https://github.com/fnando/aitch`

And there is the old method [using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47419460/8478892):

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
url = URI.parse('https://url/api')
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = (url.scheme == 'https')
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
request.content_type = 'application/json
response = http.request(request)
```

In this second case, I really don't know if it would make more sense to put it on the controller or on the model. Anyway, it's an old way of doing it. If anyone has a better way than these two, it would help a lot.

Comment: There is nothing old about the `Net::HTTP`, it's alive and kicking https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html

Comment: You could put in a call back on the model, or create a service object to handle the logic and call the method to send the webhook programatically